# URL rewrite for one page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, function, mod-rewrite

I have a bilingual wordpress site that adds the language subdomain into the URL (e.g., `mysite.com/en/first-page/`. I am trying to find a simple way (can it be done via the `functions.php` file?) to rewrite the URL to have it remove the `/en/`, making the URL `mysite.com/first-page/`. Is this possible? I've looked at some tuts and a lot of them focus on stuff like archives and categories and I'm not sure they can help me.

Comment: Are you only using English with your WordPress?

Comment: @Twisty No, it's bilingual. The plugin hardcodes the language into the URL depending on what language your on.

Comment: so how would the PHP or URL Rewrite know which language to use if the url path is changed?

Comment: This page will have copy in both languages, so there won't be a translated page (meaning there won't be an /en/first-page/ and /fr/first-page/. Since there is only one page, I'd like to remove the language ID in the URL. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No. If I navigate to `mysite.com/first-page/`, how should the web server know which language my preference is? now, if the URL was `en.mysite.com/first-page/` and `fr.mysite.com/first-page/`, this would allow me to know the preference and rewrite it to a specific folder or pass a variable.

Comment: @Twisty, because the language preference for a page with slug `^first-page/$` will *always* be rewritten to `en/first-page/`. This only applies to one page; so the OP's requirements are completely fine.

Comment: @mevius I'm, not sure I am tracking what you're saying. OP Wants to use 2 languages, English and French. So it will NOT always be rewritten to English. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Twisty I don't want to use a second language at all. My plugin hard codes the language subdomains into the URL's whenever I create a page; there is no way to create a page without having /en/ or /fr/ in the URL. I am trying to rewrite the URL to remove those.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a *functions.php* solution, you may be able to use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). Something like:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^first-page/?', 'en/first-page/');
```

If that doesn't work, you should consider adding a rule to .htaccess.

Comment: How would I do it via the .htaccess file?